# What does the number I see mean when flagging as a duplicate?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

When flagging as a duplicate, I see a number next to the duplicate question:

[image]

What does the 3 here mean? Is that the number of duplicate flags pointing to that question? Is it votes to close as duplicate? Is this something a low-rep user (<2k) should be able to see?

(I think votes to close as duplicate is less likely, but the threshold to view such information is a lot lower than to view flags, so I figured "why not?".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bring your mouse over it, it tells you that that's how many people have already voted to close it under that category.

Quoting the tooltip message, "this many votes already exist".

And I don't see any reason for that information to only be restricted to users with a 2K+ rep. Anyone can flag a post, so anyone should be able to view how many votes to close already exist.

Having said that, it might be clearer to change the heading text to "Other voters chose these questions..." instead of "Other users chose these questions...".

Comment: Definitely should've moused over it before I asked this question. Also, viewing close votes only takes 250 rep, whereas casting takes 3k (and viewing flags 10k). All makes sense now.

Comment: @Jim: A lot of SE's strange stuff is explained via tooltip :/